# Attribute error when loading export.pkl model using load_learner. Works without gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am making a flask API with gunicorn to inference multiple machine learning .pkl models. Without gunicorn, everything works fine locally but when I try to use it with gunicorn (ie. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app), every model works except for one where I get the error:

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'map3' on module '**main**' from '/Users/***/***/***/env/bin/gunicorn'

When loading the learner. Every model was made and exported the same way so I am unsure why the other work. The function that queries the model works when I switch out the model it's using so it is something wrong with gunicorn and the pkl files compatibility.